# Could an advertising campaing be legally imitated if it is based on public domain images?

Tags: copyright, creative-commons

The case I am thinking about is absolutely hypothetical. The company XYZ asks an agency to create an advertising campaign. Outsourcing after outsourcing the work ends up on a gig site and it is done by a remote worker who uses images taken from Wikipedia or any other site with Creative Commons licence without telling it to the client.

What happens if a competitor or imitation brand XYz find out? Could XYz run a campaign using the same pictures? Could the competitor use those images to create an ironic version of the campaign?

Answer (score 3):

### The campaign is a copyrighted work distinct from any work it contains

Consider this answer - even though it’s made up of uncopyrightable words, the particular arrangement of those words is a copyrighted work. The same is true of an arrangement of pictures.

While the competitor is free to use the pictures, they can’t use the campaign.

The ironic version is fine providing it is a true parody. Parody is an fair use under copyright law.

Comment: v informative answer .  I imagine there can be some quite interesting cases [/disputes] involving the use of parody